# How do I use a dd-created image, that's bigger than the original disk?

Tags: raspberry-pi, dd, sdhc, disk-imaging

I created a backup of flash card, using:  `dd bs=4M if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=backup.img`

Now, trying to restore that back to the same card with Etcher, I'm told the image is bigger than the card, and I need 300+Mb of more space.

Should I be creating the image a different way?  Is there a work-around to restoring the image?  If it matters, I'm trying to maintain all of the needed partitions for a RaspberryPi.  I'm new at this, so any guidance would be great (including if there's a more appropriate Exchange to ask).

Answer (score 0):

Since my question was focused in particular on a RPi .img file, there is a utility, PiShrink https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Drewsif/PiShrink/master/pishrink.sh
for this very task.